# Relative path in HTML works for CSS, not for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iis

On our IIS server, a relative path to a stylesheet works just fine...

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/styles.css">`

But a relative path to a Javascript file doesn't work...

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script> <!-- This won't load!! -->`

And an absolute path to a Javascript file DOES work...

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.somecdn.com/jquery.js">`

And inline Javascript is just fine, too...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("You'll see me, that's for sure!");
</script>
```

Relative paths to images are also fine...

`<image src="path/to/image.png" alt="You can see me!" />`

So I'm wondering if there's an IIS setting somewhere which is changing the way paths work based on the MIME type of the resource being requested. Is there some other reason that a relative path to a stylesheet would work and a relative path to a javascript file wouldn't? Apparently this is an issue that's been brought up to the IT folk here and they don't seem to know what could be causing the problem.

Comment: Do you have any sort of mod rewriting going on?

Comment: It's not an Apache server, but there's probably something similar to mod_rewrite going on. I'm just a front-end developer here so I'm not sure the ins and outs of how the server is configured, unfortunately.

Comment: @Andrewlafrate IIS supports mod re-writing through the use of ISAPI filters.  In IIS, there is an ISAPI Filters tab in the properties of the website.  See if there is anything in that tab.  Next, you could navigate to the page where your script is not loaded.  See if the path is somewhat similar to your absolute path.

Comment: Could you test your theory by putting a non-JS file in the directory that you are having trouble referencing? For example, but a file called notjs.txt in your scripts directory and load it as a javascript file using a script tag. This might allow you to validate your MIME type theory. Good luck.

Comment: How does your javascript file look?